# Default value for a field in changeset

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a model and changeset method. I want to have an optional field to which I want to set a default value if it doesn't get passed to chargeset. How can I do that?

Comment: How about just doing `params = Map.put_new(params, "field", default_value)` before sending it to `cast`?

Comment: @Dogbert Is this the accepted way of defaulting? For example a Role for a User: `params = Map.put_new(params, :role_id, 2)`

Answer (score 23):

When you create your schema, you can give it a default value by passing it the `:default` atom.

```
schema "foo" do
  field :name, :string, default: "bar"
end
```

Comment: Can you default an association like this?

Comment: Yes. Just keep in mind that the default key is calculated at compile time. So if you do database access to find the foreign key, it will do the database access only at compile time and not for every insert.

Answer (score 7):

Justin's answer is definitely most elegant if your needs are simple, but in my case I needed a little more flexibility.  I needed to be able to generate a unique, cryptographically secure value.

I did it in my changeset pipeline:

```
def changeset(build_proxy, attrs) do
  build_proxy
  |> cast(attrs, [:avatar, :channel, :username, :service_base_url])
  |> gen_api_token_if_empty()
  |> validate_required([:avatar, :channel, :username, :service_base_url])
end                                                                                   

defp gen_api_token_if_empty(changeset) do
  case get_change(changeset, :api_token) do
    nil -> put_change(changeset, :api_token, gen_api_token())
     "" -> put_change(changeset, :api_token, gen_api_token())
      _ -> changeset
  end
end

defp gen_api_token() do
  :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(80)
  |> Base.url_encode64
  |> binary_part(0, length)
end
```

Comment: A better solution to this may be to create your own ecto type and have it autogenerate the value for you.

Comment: @JustinWood Thanks for the suggestion!  That does sound better.  I'm a total elixir noob at the moment, is https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html what you're referring to?

Comment: In your example, I think `gen_api_token_if_empty/1` is _always_ going to 'think' that field is empty – you didn't include `:api_token` in the list for the `permitted` argument in the call to `cast/3`.